# How to set message when I get Exception

Tags: java, android

```
public class XMLParser {

    // constructor
    public XMLParser() {

    }


    public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
        String responseBody = null;

        getset d1 = new getset();
        String d = d1.getData(); // text
        String y = d1.getYear(); // year
        String c = d1.getCircular();
        String p = d1.getPage();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("YearID", y));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("CircularNo", c));

        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("SearchText", d));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pagenumber", p));
        try {

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(entity);

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // return XML
        return responseBody;
    }


    public Document getDomElement(String xml) {
        Document doc = null;
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        try {

            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is);

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());

            // i m getting Exception here

            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
    }

    /**
     * Getting node value
     * 
     * @param elem
     *            element
     */
    public final String getElementValue(Node elem) {
        Node child;
        if (elem != null) {
            if (elem.hasChildNodes()) {
                for (child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child
                        .getNextSibling()) {
                    if (child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE) {
                        return child.getNodeValue();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

    /**
     * Getting node value
     * 
     * @param Element
     *            node
     * @param key
     *            string
     * */
    public String getValue(Element item, String str) {
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
}
```

I am getting Exception in this class for parsing data. I want print this message in another class which extends from Activity. Can you please tell me how? I tried much but not able to do..

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends Activity {

    public int currentPage = 1;
    public ListView lisView1;
    static final String KEY_ITEM = "docdetails";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "heading";
    public Button btnNext;
    public Button btnPre;
    public static String url = "http://dev.taxmann.com/TaxmannService/TaxmannService.asmx/GetNotificationList";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        // listView1
        lisView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

        // Next
        btnNext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNext);
        // Perform action on click
        btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage + 1;
                ShowData();
            }
        });

        // Previous
        btnPre = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPre);
        // Perform action on click
        btnPre.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                currentPage = currentPage - 1;
                ShowData();
            }
        });

        ShowData();
    }

    public void ShowData() {
        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML

        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

        int displayPerPage = 5; // Per Page
        int TotalRows = nl.getLength();
        int indexRowStart = ((displayPerPage * currentPage) - displayPerPage);
        int TotalPage = 0;
        if (TotalRows <= displayPerPage) {
            TotalPage = 1;
        } else if ((TotalRows % displayPerPage) == 0) {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage);
        } else {
            TotalPage = (TotalRows / displayPerPage) + 1; // 7
            TotalPage = (int) TotalPage; // 7
        }
        int indexRowEnd = displayPerPage * currentPage; // 5
        if (indexRowEnd > TotalRows) {
            indexRowEnd = TotalRows;
        }

        // Disabled Button Next
        if (currentPage >= TotalPage) {
            btnNext.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnNext.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Disabled Button Previos
        if (currentPage <= 1) {
            btnPre.setEnabled(false);
        } else {
            btnPre.setEnabled(true);
        }

        // Load Data from Index
        int RowID = 1;
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        // RowID
        if (currentPage > 1) {
            RowID = (displayPerPage * (currentPage - 1)) + 1;
        }

        for (int i = indexRowStart; i < indexRowEnd; i++) {
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
            // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));
            map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            menuItems.add(map);

            RowID = RowID + 1;

        }

        SimpleAdapter sAdap;
        sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item, new String[] { "RowID", KEY_NAME },
                new int[] { R.id.ColRowID, R.id.ColName });
        lisView1.setAdapter(sAdap);
    }

}
```

This my class where I want to Print that message

Comment: implement an interface in your `XMLParser`. And set results there...

Comment: I hope your issue was solved. Am i right?

Answer (score 2):

You can simply surround your code with a `Try/Catch` block like this:

```
String xml;
Document doc;
NodeList nl;

try {

    xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML
    doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
    nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This way you don't have to make any changes in your `XMLParser` class and you can easily handle any exceptions occurring while parsing your code in the main class itself. Also, for displaying error messages, `Toast` is the best thing according to me.

Hope this helps.. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would say, add `throws SAXException` in `XMLParser.getDomElement()` method and don't catch `SAXException` in this method as:

```
  public Document getDomElement(String xml) throws SAXException {
```

Catch the `SAXException` in `AndroidXMLParsingActivity.ShowData()` where you are calling `getDomElement()` method and print the message in the desired way e.g.

```
 public void ShowData() {
    XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url); // getting XML

    Document doc = null;
    try{
          doc  = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element
      }catch(SAXException sae){
         //print the desired message here
      }

      .......
      .......
 }
```

Comment: No its not when i trieed to apply this thenAndroidXMLParsingActivity not able to Pic the Exception

Comment: please tell ur email i ll send u Source code its small work but i dont know here i m doing wrong i m trying to implement it from last 2 days not able to do plz help me

Comment: its not there please tell me ur email id i ll send complete source code so that u can understand where i m doing wrong please help me

Comment: hii i sent mail please help me and do Implement it

Answer (score 1):

Simply pass the constructor to your `XMLParser` class and used that there as your constructor. Or, you can try with use of `getApplicationContext()` You can simply show the `Toast` when you getting an exception like below -

```
try {

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
    doc = db.parse(is);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeToast(con, e.toString(), Toast.Long).show();   // Will show the message of exception
    return null;
} catch (SAXException e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeToast(con, e.toString(), Toast.Long).show();   // Will show the message of exception
    // i m getting Exception here
    return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeToast(con, e.toString(), Toast.Long).show();   // Will show the message of exception
    return null;
}
```

**Update**

Okay, just pass the constructor as per below - Where you are calling that `XMLparser` class just call like below -

```
....
XMLParser xml = new XMLParser(AndroidXMLParsingActivity.this);
....
```

And, in `XMLParser` class there mention your constructor like below -

```
public class XMLParser {

    Context con;

    public XMLParser(Context context) {

        con = context;

    }
......
}
```

And, use this `con` as your constructor in your `XMLParser` class.

Comment: But Exception is not coming in extends  Activity class how i will Print?

Comment: @user1748932 Try the updated code. And, first just try with `getApplicationContext()` or pass the context to your `parseXML` class and use that there.

Comment: that i want to know how to Pass context to parsexml class

Comment: asking   Toast.makeToast(getApplicationContext(), e.toString(), Toast.Long).show();   create method getApplicationContext()

Answer (score 1):

For showing Message from Non Activity Class you will need to pass Current Activity Context as:

```
public class XMLParser {

Context context
    // constructor
    public XMLParser(Context conts) {
    context =conts;
    }
///YOUR CODE
try {

    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource();
    is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
    doc = db.parse(is);

} catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeToast(context, e.toString(), Toast.Long).show();   
    return null;
} catch (SAXException e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeToast(context, e.toString(), Toast.Long).show();  
    // i m getting Exception here
    return null;
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
    Toast.makeToast(context, e.toString(), Toast.Long).show();  
    return null;
}
```